# Regex to filter out characteristics behind specific string

Tags: regex, powershell

it is not my first question regarding regex, however I'm stil struggling pretty hard to get the expressions to work as I intend them to do.

I have a line of structured text with different information. I just want to keep the two characteristics `Connector:` and `E_DE_HH:`

Let me provide an example text line:

```
[10:26:33]: Connector: 8965 Info1: 8 Info2: 8 Info3: 4 E_DE_HH: 6000 Info4: 99
```

Output should be:

```
8965 6000
```

Which expression could provide me with the correct output? I tried to replace everything except the data behind the named characteristics, but that filterd out everythin. I'm confused about these expressions..

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter could be: `.* Connector: ([0-9]*) .* E_DE_HH: ([0-9]*) .*` and your substitution would be: `\1 \2`.

See this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1KfX0e/2) for an example.

Comment: The link looks quite good, is it possible to leave out the time in front? I don't need it. :)

Comment: @MIke_H Updated

Comment: I'm no powershell expert, but perhaps use `$1` and `$2` instead of `\1` and `\2`. See https://powershell.org/2013/08/regular-expressions-are-a-replaces-best-friend/

Comment: As powershell is very picky about spaces this is the final correct regex that is working fine for me ```.*ConnID:\s([0-9]*).*\sE_MAX_ENTRIES:\s([0-9]*).*```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-match` operator over your string and use `$matches` variable then to substitute matched groups.

```
PS Y:\> '[10:26:33]: Connector: 8965 Info1: 8 Info2: 8 Info3: 4 E_DE_HH: 6000 Info4: 99' -match 'Connector: (\d*).*E_DE_HH: (\d*)'
True

PS Y:\> "$($matches[1]) $($matches[2])"
8965 6000
```

Comment: That's a neat way as well. Thank you!